# Using Swift Mailer messages with AWS SES API, but with streams

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, swiftmailer, amazon-ses

I'm trying to implement sending emails using the official AWS SDK for PHP, through AWS SES.
I'm using `php 7.2`

My problem is with attachments. If I want to send attachments, I need to use the [sendRawEmail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-email-2010-12-01.html#sendrawemail) method from the sdk. It accepts a `Data` key, than can be one of the following: `<string || resource || Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface>`

Now, I am building my message using [Swift_Message](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/class-Swift_Message.html). This class has a `toString()` method than can be used to obtain the raw string of the email. Sending this raw string to the above `sendRawEmail` method works as expected and the email is successfully sent.

The problem with attachments is that, if we have a 5MB attachment, `toString` will generate a large string that will occupy memory. I would like to avoid this.

`Swift_Message` also has a `toByteStream` method that is able to write the message to a `Swift_InputByteStream` , but I have no idea how to use this with the AWS sdk and make sure that the string is streamed in chunks, in order to save memory.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a problem honestly, the email attachment is sent as base64 encoded string, that's exactly what you are going to receive when you look at the source of the email. What do you mean by "large string that occupy memory", how is that reflected?